# Converting ArgoUML to SQL

Tags: sql, argouml

I was wondering if there any program that can convert ArgoUML files into sql code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try [argouml-db](http://argouml-db.tigris.org). It uses [this plugin](http://argouml-sql.tigris.org/) for argo.